# Https Connection subdomain URL change

Tags: java, url, wicket, wicketstuff

Https Connection subdomain

Im Looking to set up my wickets 1.5 application with HTTPS.

I have added the following to my Application Class.

```
setRootRequestMapper(new HttpsMapper(getRootRequestMapper(), new HttpsConfig(8080, 8443)));
mountPage("/go/securepage", securePage.class);
```

As i have annotated the securePage.class with `"@RequireHttps"` the Link correctly loads the page with HTTPS.

However i want to forward all https connections to a seperate subdomain.

So instead of going to

`https://www.example.com/go/securepage` the user is forwarded to
`https://securepage.example.com/go/securepage`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never needed to do this, but looking at the sources of [`HttpsMapper`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/protocol/https/HttpsMapper.html) it seems you will we able to do this by overriding [`HttpsMapper.mapHandler()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket-core/1.5-RC4.2/org/apache/wicket/protocol/https/HttpsMapper.java#HttpsMapper.mapHandler%28org.apache.wicket.request.IRequestHandler%29).

```
public Url mapHandler(IRequestHandler requestHandler) {
        Url url = delegate.mapHandler(requestHandler);
        switch (checker.getProtocol(requestHandler)){
            case HTTP :
                url.setProtocol("http");
                url.setPort(httpsConfig.getHttpPort());
                break;
            case HTTPS :
                url.setProtocol("https");
                url.setPort(httpsConfig.getHttpsPort());
                break;
        }
        return url;
    }
```

So, you can override it like this:

```
setRootRequestMapper(new HttpsMapper(getRootRequestMapper(), new HttpsConfig(8080, 8443)){
    @Override
    public Url mapHandler(IRequestHandler requestHandler) {
        Url url = super.mapHandler(requestHandler);
        if ("https".equals(url.getProtocol)){
            // Force the HostName for HTTPS requests
            url.setHost("securepage.example.com");   
        }
        return url;
    }
});
```